# Jenkins error - cannot connect to repository

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins and trying to connect Jenkins to the repository I created on GitHub (I have Windows8.1). After trying for two days I am asking this question. I went through all the question asked before on SO but no luck.

1. I have installed Git and Github plugin on Jenkins.
2. I have given correct git.exe path in Jenkin's configuration.
3. I have installed Git.

When I click on the job and click on Configure it opens Git setup wizard even though I have already installed Git and it keeps opening it again and again even though I cancel it. At the end it shows me error in Jenkins.

[image: Git setup]

[image: Error after cancelling Git setup]

Comment: how do you start Jenkins? on windows 8.1 there is a high chance that it is UAC related. make sure you run jenkins as windows Admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Git wasn't installed properly. So I uninstalled Git and installed it again. 
After installation the Git folder was created and git.exe was in C:Git\bin\git.exe (This path changes per where you install your Git). I gave this path in the Jenkins configurations. Thast solved my problem.